# Mail header fields: Practical difference between quoted-printable and 7bit?

Tags: email, encoding, header-fields

Is there any practical difference between "7bit" and "quoted-printable" as Content-Transfer-Encoding in email? From all I could gather the encoding schemes are virtually identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, in 7bit, you can have a space at the end of a line, but in quoted-printable, you have to write it as =20 (which would be interpreted literally by 7bit).